# How to handle push notifications when the user is not logged in?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I am confused about how to handle notifications in the react-native app if the user is not logged in. I send push notifications via OneSignal to the application but if a user is not logged in I should not send a notification, how can I check user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 2):

When logging out, you can try to call `OneSignal.removeExternalUser()` method. And logging in, `OneSignal.setExternalUserId(userId)`.